# html5 form submit to onclick js function: nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, sinatra

Apologies in advance if I don't use the correct terminology.
I've been given a simple sinatra api to work with users and groups.
I've been working through the logic of it all, and while everything seems to be working, I can't get the onclick to call the issuccess js function. I tried doing the event listener. I'm just lost now, please help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="loginform cf">
        <form name="login" method="post" onclick="return isSuccess()" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="usermail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required></li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value= "login" \>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function isSuccess(){
        var firstAdmin = {
            "name": "Admin",
            "email": "admin@example.com",
            "password": "secret",
            "admin": true
            };
        $.post("main.rb", firstAdmin);

        function isValidUser() {
            $.get( "/users", function(data) {
                var x=document.form.usermail.value;
                var y=document.form.password.value;
                if (x === users.email && y === users.password && users.admin === true){
                    window.location="userprofile/adminprofile.html";
                }
                if (x === users.email && y === users.password && users.admin === false){
                    window.location="userprofile/userprofile.html";
                }
            alert( "success" );
            })



            });
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are using `$get` correctly. Have you looked up the documentation for it?

> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

At the present moment you are ignoring the result of get when you do:

```
if ($.get('/users') = 200){
```

since that function immediately returns (regardless of whether the Sinatra API request was completed). You need to pass in a callback function which is immediately called at some later time when the request does actually complete:

```
$.get( "/users", function(data) {
  //automatically get here if return status is 200
  alert( "success" );
})
```